# My Android widget is killed, "No longer want bellander.andro...."

Tags: android, widget, android-widget

I'm writing a widget that pulls data from a web page every 5 minutes, using a timer. This works fine for an hour or two, then the process is killed.

```
I/ActivityManager(81): No longer want bellander.android.widget (pid 1118): hidden #16
```

and the system kills of the process. How do I prevent this? Is the use of a timer wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm writing a widget that pulls data
>   from a web page every 5 minutes, using
>   a timer

Please use `AlarmManager` for this. Do not attempt to have a service (or, worse, an `AppWidgetProvider`) [live forever](http://www.androidguys.com/2009/09/09/diamonds-are-forever-services-are-not/).

Also, [please make the period configurable and disable-able](http://www.androidguys.com/2010/03/29/code-pollution-background-control/). Just because you want five-minute-polling does not mean your users always will.

Comment: I have worked around the AlarmManager because all examples/docs I could find were so crappy (though I have not looked at yours). But now, after some trail and error, I have got it to work and it is really simple! I cant believe the docs are so bad for something this simple.. I think I have to write an example widget using the AlarmManager.. Thanks for the help!